# Parametric surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$ via quaternion multiplication of curves

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras

In this question, $\mathbb{R}^4$ is identified with the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ via the map $$(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) \mapsto a_1+ia_2+ja_3+ka_4,$$ 
where $1,i,j,k$ are the standard basis elements of the quaternion ring $\mathbb{H}$.

A curve $r(t)=(u(t), v(t), p(t), q(t)): \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^4$ can then be regarded as an $\mathbb{H}$-valued function $r(t)=u +i v + j p + kq$.  Let $h(w)=a+ib+jc+kd$ be another curve, and assume that $u,v,p,q,a,b,c,d$ are real differentiable functions of class $C^{\infty}$.

Consider the parametric surfaces $S(t, w)=r(t)h(w)$, and $T(t,w)=h(w)r(t)$, where quaternion multiplication is implied. 
If $E^S,F^S, G^S, E^T, F^T, G^T$ are the coefficients of the first fundamental forms of $S$ and $T$, respectively, then $E^S=E^T, G^S=G^T$, while $F^S \ne F^T$ in general. If, however, $F^S=F^T$, then the surfaces $S(t,w)$ and $T(t,w)$ have the same Gaussian curvaure (wherever they are smooth) because they are (intrinsically) isometric.

CONJECTURE: There exists an ambient isometry $L\colon \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ satisfying $L(S(t,w))=T(t,w)$ if and only if $F^S = F^T$, i.e., if and only if the surfaces $S$ and $T$ are isometric.

There are several cases in which the above is true. So,my question is:

QUESTION: Is the above Conjecture true?

Comment: You want an isometry $L$, not just a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Isotopic and ambiently diffeomorphic is not quite the same. And, indeed, do you want a diffeomorphism (and then why the metric) or an isometry?

Comment: "(...) if and only if $F+F^T$" ?

Comment: Sorry, in the  CONJECTURE,  I meant ``if and only if  F=F^T.''

Comment: @Takis S. :  With $h(w) = cos(w) + sin(w)i $ and $r(t)=cos(t) + sin(t)i + cos(2t)j + sin(2t) k$ it seems to me that the Gaussian curvature of both surfaces $S$ and $T$ are zero but $F^S \neq F^T$.